# Make a notification ring when App launched or not (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android, notifications, xamarin.forms

I am using the **dependency Service**  `DependencyService.Get<ISetAlarm>().SetAlarm(hour,min,"Diabetics App","Hello i remind you to take medicine");`, which connects to my `AlarmReceiver` and `AlarmImplementation` class, 
**the problem is :**

> When i place the **Dependency Service** code in any form the Notification
>   only comes when i launch that form , when i put in `onStart,onSleep`
>   methods the notification comes only in such states , how can i make
>   the application to make notifications **like a real alarm** , when either it's
>   launched or not?.

**ADDITIONALLLY:**

**AlarmReceiver class**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using Android.Widget;
using Diabetes.localDB;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action.Equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
            {
            var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");



            //Show toast here
            //Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello it's me ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                NotificationManager manager_ = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager_.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }

            //Create intent for action 1 (TAKE)
            var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
            actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
            var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            //Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
            var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
            actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
            var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);

            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            //seting an alarm
            MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
            var alarm_list = db.GetAlarmList();
            //Debug.WriteLine(" Time -- : "+ m.ToString());


            // Instantiate the Big Text style:
            Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();


            var builder =
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent1)
                                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "REPLY", pIntent2)
                                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .SetContentTitle("Diabetics Reminder")
                                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                                .SetStyle(new Notification
                                .BigTextStyle()
                                .SetSummaryText("")
                                .SetBigContentTitle(title)
                                .BigText(message)
             ).SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            builder.SetContentIntent(pending);

            var notification = builder.Build();


            var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            manager.Notify(10010, notification);
        }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "ARCHIVE", "REPLY" })]
    public class CustomActionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            switch (intent.Action)
            {
                case "ARCHIVE":
                    try
                    {
                        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
                        db.addtracktaken("true");
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "DOSAGE TAKEN", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    }
                    break;
                case "REPLY":
                    try
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "ARCHIVE", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
                        db.addtrackmissed("true");
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "DOSAGE MISSED", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                NotificationManager manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AlarmImplementation class**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SetAlarmImplementation))]
namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    public class SetAlarmImplementation : ISetAlarm
    {

        public void SetAlarm(int hour, int minute, string title, string message, string)
        {

            MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
            var alarm_list = db.GetAlarmList();
            //Debug.WriteLine(" Time -- : "+ m.ToString());




            Intent myintent = new Intent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            myintent.PutExtra("message", message);
            myintent.PutExtra("title", title);
            PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
            Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
            cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
            //  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pendingintent);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is my new Update

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Diabetes.localDB;
using Diabetes.Main;

namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MainApplication")]
    public class MainApplication : Activity
    {
        ISetAlarm alarmService;
        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();

        public MainApplication(){

        }
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            alarmService = new SetAlarmImplementation();
            //Get list of stored time from Sqlite
            var alarm_list = db.GetAlarmList();
            //Debug.WriteLine(" Time -- : "+ m.ToString());
            var message = "Hello Its I remind you to take insulin";
            var title = "Diabetics App";
            foreach (var list in alarm_list)
            {
                var hour = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(0, 2));
                var minute = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(3, 2));
                alarmService.SetAlarm(hour, minute, title,message);
                // Create your application here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i have done but now when i set the time no notification comes , it's like there's somehow i have to make it trigger.

I think am close to the answer, i need some more guidance thanks.

EDIT 2:

Check out My Sqlite DB class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite.Net;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Diabetes.localDB
{
    public class MedicationDatabase
    {
        private SQLiteConnection _connection;

        public MedicationDatabase()
        {

            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            _connection.CreateTable<Medication>();
            _connection.CreateTable<SetReminder>();
            // _connection.CreateTable<Track>();
            _connection.CreateTable<TrackMissed>();
            _connection.CreateTable<TrackTaken>();
            _connection.CreateTable<LoginModel>();


        }
        public void AddDetails(string username, string alarm_time, string units, string insulin_type, string unique_id, string status)
        {

            _connection.Query<Medication>("Insert into [Medication] (username, alarm_time, units,insulin_type,unique_id,status) values" +
                                          "('" + username + "','" + alarm_time + "','" + units + "','" + insulin_type + "','" + unique_id + "','" + status + "')");

        }


        public void AddReminder(string username, string alarm_time,
                             string units, string insulin_type, string count_times)
        {

            _connection.Query<SetReminder>("Insert into [SetReminder] (username, alarm_time, units,insulin_type,count_times) values" +
                                          "('" + username + "','" + alarm_time + "','" + units
                                           + "','" + insulin_type + "','" + count_times + "')");
        }

        public IEnumerable<Medication> AllMedicationResults()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
                    select t).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<SetReminder> AllReminders()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<SetReminder>()
                    select t).ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetAlarmList()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
                    select t.alarm_time).ToList();
        }


        /* public string AlarmSample(){
             return (_connection.Table<SetReminder>().Select(r => r.)
            .AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(r => r.Substring(1, r.Length - 2).Split(','))).ToList().ToString()
                                                                            ;        }*/

        public IEnumerable<string> GetUnitsList()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
                    select t.units).ToList();
        }

        public void DeleteAlarm()
        {
            _connection.DeleteAll<SetReminder>();
        }


        public void DeleteTime(int id)
        {

            _connection.Delete<Medication>(id);
        }

        public void DeleteAllTime()
        {
            _connection.DeleteAll<Medication>();
        }

        // Tracking table 
        public void addtracktaken(string taken)
        {

            _connection.Query<TrackTaken>("Insert into [TrackTaken] (taken) values" +
                                          "('" + taken + "')");
        }

        public void addtrackmissed(string missed)
        {

            _connection.Query<TrackMissed>("Insert into [TrackMissed] (missed) values" +
                                           "('" + missed + "')");
        }

        public int GetTracksTakenNos()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<TrackTaken>()
                    select t.taken).Count();
        }

        public int GetTracksMissedNo()
        {
            return (from t in _connection.Table<TrackMissed>()
                    select t.missed).Count();
        }

        //Loging in 
        public void addUser(string username, string logged)
        {

            _connection.Query<LoginModel>("Insert into [LoginModel] (username,LoggedIn) values" +
                                          "('" + username + "', '" + logged + "')");
        }

        public void DeleteUsers()
        {
            _connection.DeleteAll<LoginModel>();
        }

        public string LoggedInStatus()
        {
            List<LoginModel> list = _connection.Query<LoginModel>("Select LoggedIn From [LoginModel] where ID=1");
            return list[0].LoggedIn;

        }

        public string GetUserName()
        {
            List<LoginModel> list = _connection.Query<LoginModel>("Select username From [LoginModel] where ID=1");
            return list[0].username;

        }

    }
}
```

And the Interface:

```
namespace Diabetes.localDB
{
    public interface ISQLite
    {
        SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with this plugin:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Notifier/ ?
It already handles the AlarmManager for you and provide a PCL implementation.

Comment: Yes @RodrigoE., i tried it but it misses alot of functionalities , thats why i ended up using Dependency Service

Comment: @IdrisStack Are you saying the notification fires immediately when you call `.SetAlarm`?

Comment: Yeah , and what i like is to make the App react like a real alarm , am i supposed to use a special method like onSleep, onpause etc to achieve this , because i tried to place it in App.cs , but the Notification pops when i launch the App , it cant pop when the Scheduled time has reached

Comment: It also  pops on the page where i call `.SetAlarm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use a DependencyService because is dependant of Xamarin Forms initialization so it will just work when application is opened. You cannot have any Xamarin Forms related call being executed when application close, since MainActivity is not available at that point and Xamarin Forms relays on it.

Will suggest instead to do the following:

1.Create an Android Application class

2.Create the instance of your alarm service there.

3.Set the alarm

```
 [Application]
 public class MainApplication : Application
 {
     ISetAlarm alarmService;
     public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) :base(handle, transer)
     {
     }

     public override void OnCreate()
     {
        base.OnCreate();
        alarmService = new SetAlarmImplementation();
        alarmService.SetAlarm(hour,min,"Diabetics App","Hello i remind you to take medicine");

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply @Rendy, i editted my post but now i don't receive any notification

Comment: You don’t receive when hen application closed or opened?

Comment: Btw, the code you modified is wrong you keep using an Activity to initialize your alarm you just renamed it to MainApppication.

Comment: Look carefully at my code and yours you will see differences you are using [Activity] attribute i’m using [Application] attribute. You are inheriting from Activity class mine is inheriting from Application class.

Comment: I editted it now but still fighting with **TargetInvocation Exception** it requires `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this);`, am trying to put it but has some errors

Comment: This thing is so hot am getting this error `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.`

Comment: You are using xamarin forms before being intialized. That you can’t do

Comment: `MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase(); ` , is the one which helps me to access time list data from PCL , i think its the one comaplaining , how can i get rid of using XF before initialized

Comment: What are you using inside that class that is xamarin forma specific?

Comment: It is for Sqlite and there's a table which retrieves list of time set, so i get this time and i wire it in the Application

Comment: But sqlite doesn’t require xamarin forms you seem to be using some xamarin forms feature. Remove the xamarin forms namespace there and that should give you an idea of what you are using.

Comment: Also remove this line `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ISetAlarm),typeof(SetAlarmImplementation))`

Comment: This line is the one using Xamarin.Forms  `_connection = `DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();` , check i have editted the codes , and i don't if i remove it it won't cause chaos

Comment: You need to don’t relay on dependency service for this instances, if not you won’t be able to execute code when application closed because forms is not initialized. Because forms is not initialized when app is closed.

Comment: Ok let me remove that , but what can i do for this line `Intent myintent = new Intent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            myintent.PutExtra("message", message);`, it says Nullpointer Exception

Comment: Use Android.App.Application.Context instead of Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context

Comment: thanks so much for that issue i successfully removed it thanks so much , but i have left with one problem when i remove the Application in the background, It doesnt make an alarm. I know i have disturebed you alot but still thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Start a sticky service on your application class OnCreate method so that even do the application closes, the service will keep the application alive and you can still get notifications.

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public static Context AppContext;
    public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

        StartService();
    }

    public static void StartService()
    {
        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
                    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

}
```

Create a sticky service class:

```
[Service]
public class AppStickyService : Service
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Created");
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Started");
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override Android.OS.IBinder OnBind(Android.Content.Intent intent)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Binded");
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Destroyed");
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: One note you shouldn't close the app while debugging. You can stop the app and then reopen and close again. But never close it during debugging because Android doesn't handle that situation well.

Comment: I have tried this code , i first placed  `alarmService.SetAlarm(hour,min,"Diabetics App","Hello i remind you to take medicine"); ` then  `StartService()` it crashed when the time set reached  and also i did it the reverse way nothing came , am i supposed to put all the Alarm Implementation code in **StartService()** Method?

Comment: please accept my friend request on Facebook my name is **Lutaaya Huzaifah Idris**

Comment: I don't know how i will thank you but , your answer helped me so much @Rendy , you deserve a cup of capucino